# Will the expansion files be deleted when an user removes your application from there phone / tablet?

Tags: android, assets, expansion

Google just gave us a [new option to add expansion files](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html) to our android apps. Very great idea!

But something is bugging me for a long time in Android and I'm wondering if the Google developers have solved that issue with this solution.

When I'm downloading application with extra assets (without this solution), they will be downloaded to my sdcard. No problem as long as I'm using that app. But when I remove that app the assets remain there.

So, my question is will the expansion files be deleted when a user uninstalls / removes the app from there phone or tablet with this new solution?

Comment: *"But when I remove that app the assets remain there."* - That's only correct when the app programmer didn't make proper use of [`getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) and [`getExternalCacheDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29).

Comment: Ok. Didn't know about that. But I guess a lot of apps are not doing this correct then. 
But the question remains, if the new solution will handle this automatically for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files will be deleted if they are on API Level 8 or higher, this is not specific to the new expansion files support but is due to where the expansion files are stored (in the app specific external storage location). From [Accessing files on external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles):

> If the user's device is running API Level 8 or greater and they
>   uninstall your application, this directory and all its contents will
>   be deleted.